# Install Postgres 9.2 on CentOS 6.5 using Chef

Tags: postgresql, centos, chef-infra

Env: CentOS 6.5, Chef, Vagrant, Berkshelf

- Added `cookbook "postgresql"` in my `Berksfile`
- Ran `$ berks install` followed `berks upload` which uploaded my cookbook to my hosted Enterprise Chef server.
- Added my postgresql attributes to my cookbook `my_cookbook/attributes/default.rb`

  ```
  default['postgresql']['version'] = '9.2'

  default['postgresql']['client']['packages'] = ["postgresql#{node['postgresql']['version'].split('.').join}-devel"]

  default['postgresql']['server']['packages'] = ["postgresql#{node['postgresql']['version'].split('.').join}-server"]

  default['postgresql']['contrib']['packages'] = ["postgresql#{node['postgresql']['version'].split('.').join}-contrib"]

  default['postgresql']['dir'] = "/var/lib/pgsql/#{node['postgresql']['version']}/data"

  default['postgresql']['server']['service_name'] = "postgresql-#{node['postgresql']['version']}"
  ```

In my `default.rb` recipe:

```
include_recipe 'postgresql::yum_pgdg_postgresql'
include_recipe 'postgresql::server'
```

The Error:

```
Recipe: postgresql::client
  * package[postgresql92-devel] action install
    * No version specified, and no candidate version available for postgresql92-devel
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[postgresql92-devel]'
================================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding one line in the my `attributes/default.rb`

```
default['postgresql']['enable_pgdg_yum'] = true      <==== ADDED THIS
default['postgresql']['version'] = '9.2'
default['postgresql']['client']['packages'] = ["postgresql#{node['postgresql']['version'].split('.').join}-devel"]
default['postgresql']['server']['packages'] = ["postgresql#{node['postgresql']['version'].split('.').join}-server"]
default['postgresql']['contrib']['packages'] = ["postgresql#{node['postgresql']['version'].split('.').join}-contrib"]
default['postgresql']['dir'] = "/var/lib/pgsql/#{node['postgresql']['version']}/data"
default['postgresql']['server']['service_name'] = "postgresql-#{node['postgresql']['version']}"
```