# how to I create a postgres role using chef `postgresql` cookbook?

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra

On CentOS 6.5

I am using this [postgres community cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/postgresql) and was able to able to install postgresql using chef [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738383/install-postgres-9-2-on-centos-6-5-using-chef)

Now I need to create a role using Chef, but I can't figure out how.

The following command should be run:

```
CREATE ROLE my_pg_role WITH ...
```

see [pg doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createrole.html)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a `postgresql_role` resource anywhere, but a very good starting point would be the library for [postgresql_user](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database/blob/master/libraries/provider_database_postgresql_user.rb) in the [database](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database) cookbook. This wraps around the postgres cookbook that you are already using.

Comment: those refrences are depricated